# activity feed, php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I want to make sort of an activity feed but im a little stuck on how to set up my sql query or should i make several querys can any1 point me in the right direction.

I want to output the last 10 writes in my database. For example i would have a table with users and a table with posts. consider this example.

users.id, users.firstname, users.joindate, users.profilepicture, users.picturesetdate

Posts.id, Posts.users_id, posts.message, post.postdate

I would want to output the last 10 changes. For instance

Firstname changed his profilepicture on 6-12-2016
Firstname posted a message on 5-12-2016
Firstname Joined the website on 4-12-2016

What would i need to do to get this information in the same query cus i would need to group Firstname, Profilepicture and picturesetdate. Firstname, message,postdate. Firstname, joindate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set this up fairly easily using 2 queries:

You can query your posts first and get all the columns you need:

```
$sql = "SELECT id, users_id, message, postdate from posts ORDER BY postdate DESC LIMIT 10";
$res_a = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql) or die (mysqli_error($mysqli));
```

Then start a loop displaying the results, and within that loop you can query the users table using 'users_id' from the posts table.

```
foreach ($res_a as $res) { 

// Get user ID from posts table
$userid = $res['users_id'];

// Query the users table
$user_sql = "SELECT id, firstname, joindate, profilepicture, picturesetdate FROM users WHERE id = '$userid'";
$user_res = mysqli_query($mysqli, $user_sql) or die (mysqli_error($mysqli));
$user = $user_res->fetch_assoc();
```

Then you can simply assign each result to a variable:

```
$first_name = $user['firstname'];
$profile_photo = $user['profilepicture'];
// etc..
```

Comment: decided to create a table for activity feed thanks though